# How does dropbox' response queue work, exactly?

Tags: message-queue, dropbox, google-docs

I am reading this writing: https://medium.com/@narengowda/system-design-dropbox-or-google-drive-8fd5da0ce55b. In the Synchronization Service part, it writes that:

> The Response Queues that correspond to individual subscribed clients are responsible for delivering the update messages to each client. Since a message will be deleted from the queue once received by a client, we need to create separate Response Queues for each client to be able to share an update message which should be sent to multiple subscribed clients.

The context is that `we need a response queue to send the file updates from one client to other clients`. I am confused by this statement. If Dropbox has 100 million clients, we need to create 100 million queues, based on the statement. It is unimaginable to me. For example, a Kafka cluster can support up to 5K topics ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950503/can-i-have-100s-of-thousands-of-topics-in-a-kafka-cluster#:~:text=The%20rule%20of%20thumb%20is,5K%20topics%20should%20be%20fine.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950503/can-i-have-100s-of-thousands-of-topics-in-a-kafka-cluster#:%7E:text=The%20rule%20of%20thumb%20is,5K%20topics%20should%20be%20fine.)). We need 20K Kafka clusters in this case. Which queuing system can do 100 million "topics"?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I expect such notification to clients via web-sockets only.

Additionally as [this medium blog](https://jonathangrosdubois.medium.com/if-a-client-is-offline-they-will-not-receive-the-message-221627d423fe) states that if client is not online then messages might have to be persisted in DB. After that when client comes online they can request for all updates after certain timestamp after which web sockets can be setup to facilitate future communication.

Happy to know your thoughts on this.

P.S : Most of dropbox system design blogs/vlogs have just copied from each other without going into low level detail.