# Kafka topics as chatroom identifiers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic

I am interested in a messaging chat app where different chatroom can be possible.
I try to understand if Kafka topics can be used as chatroom identifiers from Kafka conceptual point of view?

As chatrooms are normally created in a runtime then it means that

- Kafka topics should be created in a runtime. Is it possible?
- Users should be able to subscribe to the new topics (chatrooms) as soon as they are created. Is it possible?
- There will be a lot of chatrooms. Is it bad or ok for Kafka to have huge number of topics?

Comment: While this is "possible", it is a bad design, particularly for a consumer perspective. You'd be better using an actual database for storing the chats rather than seeking and   consuming the entire topic each and every time a client will open the chatroom. For example, LinkedIn + Facebook/WhatsApp might use a message-queue such as Kafka for actually "sending a chat message", but that will be consumed **and persisted** somewhere else (Facebook used to use HBase/Cassandra for this). When the chat is loaded, the database is queried, not the topic (refer CQRS pattern for details)

Comment: And with that design, you truly do not need "one topic per chat" since the consumer can read from one or few `chats` topic, and compute a `room_id`, then write to the respective tables.

Answer (score 1):

> Kafka topics should be created in a runtime. Is it possible?

Yes. [Kafka AdminClient](https://kafka.apache.org/32/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html) provides a programmatic API for administrative functionality, including listing, creating and deleting topics.

We can use [createTopics](https://kafka.apache.org/32/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/Admin.html#createTopics(java.util.Collection)) to create new topics:

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
AdminClient admin = AdminClient.create(props);


CreateTopicsResult newTopic = admin.createTopics(Collection.singletonList(new NewTopic(TOPIC_NAME, NUM_PARTITIONS, REP_FACTOR)));

admin.close(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
```

The above code comes from Kafka: The Definitive Guide 2nd Edition, Chapter 5 Managing Apache Kafka Programmatically, which discusses a lot about AdminClient.

For spring-kafka, the [KafkaAdmin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaAdmin.html) provides [createOrModifyTopics()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaAdmin.html#createOrModifyTopics(org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic...)) method.

> Users should be able to subscribe to the new topics (chatrooms) as soon as they are created. Is it possible?

Yes. We can use regular expressions in `.subscribe()`:

> The expression can match multiple topic names, and if someone creates a new topic with a name that matches, a rebalance will happen almost immediately and the consumers will start consuming from the new topic.

For example, to subscribe to all test topics, we can call

```java
consumer.subscribe(Pattern.compile("test.*"));
```

> There will be a lot of chatrooms. Is it bad or ok for Kafka to have huge number of topics?

It's okay: [Can I have 100s of thousands of topics in a Kafka Cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32950503/19322223)